# How to create responsive design flexboox boxes?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following very elegant design structure as it fits into very small screens each column is 100% returned.

```css
.five-columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.column-item {
    flex-basis: 19%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 0.5% !important;
    min-width: 240px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: chocolate;
}
```

```html
    <div class="five-columns">
        <div class="column-item">1</div>
        <div class="column-item">2</div>
        <div class="column-item">3</div>
        <div class="column-item">4</div>
        <div class="column-item">5</div>
    </div>
```

However, what I want to achieve is to create some grids of 5, except for one that must be larger than the others, like this design:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

What changes should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add another class for the double size image:

```
.double-column-item{
   Flex-grow: 2;
   Flex-basis: 38%;
 }
```

I'm not sure if you even need to double the flex-basis. If it messes up your rows you can use a flex break like this

https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/flexbox-break-to-new-row/